# Reworking WAGO 2060 on MCPCB

Tags: soldering

I have about 50 or so 1'x2' Al-clad MCPCBs, each with hundreds of LEDs attached. Each panel has 4x WAGO 2060 terminal blocks mounted at the corners.

Unfortunately the WAGO connectors have sustained some mechanical damage and I need to remove and (ideally) replace all of them (~200 PCS).

I have basic soldering skills but am having trouble using a basic soldering iron approach due to the high thermal conductivity of the MCPCB and the fact that the components are lead free soldered - i.e. I cannot get the solder to melt and the terminal blocks to detach.

The soldermask is pure white so I am also concerned about excessive and uneven heating on the circuitbaord as prior experience has shown this approach to cause soldermask discoloration (yellowing = lower reflectance).

What would be the best way to rework the damaged terminal blocks? I would be open to buying specialized equipment, with a budget of < $300 USD.

[image]

Comment: Add a photo to your post so we all know what you're talking about.

Comment: At $300, you're pretty much stuck with a standard hot air gun (no thermal control, really), so you'd have to shape an air directory using some thin aluminum.  

Another technique would be to use a gun type soldering iron, that should give you enough heat and if you add some solder to it whilst heating the pads (getting at them is the hard part) it should come off relatively easily.  You can use a 63/37 tin/lead eutectic to help lower the melting point.

Answer (score 1):

They are broken already.  Just break them some more and make your life easier:

Use diagonal cutters to clip away the damaged connector.

Then, you can unsolder and remove each pin individually.

Use a solder sucker or solder wick to clear the holes after the pins are out.

Once that is done, you can insert and solder the new connectors.

---

That is the method we used to replace bad through hole parts when I worked in a factory building 2-way radios.  It is less damaging to the PCB than trying to unsolder  a broken part.

It is also what we did if we suspected a bad part.  It was cheaper (and faster) to assume the part bad, clip it out, and replace it than to try to figure out if it was really the problem.

I mean, replace a 5cent part in five minutes or spend an hour diddling with it.  Clip out and replace wins, hands down.

Comment: I think the problem is the aluminum substrate PCB. Even if you cut it off, you can't get the new one on without the right tools.

Comment: @Jeroen3:  The hard part is getting the old part out.  Getting all pins free at once takes a lot of heat.  When you go to solder in the new connector, you are doing them one at a time.  A soldering gun or a high wattage iron would help, of course.  But, you are doing them one at a time, so you need nowhere near the heat you would to remove the connectors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but just to clarify, the [WAGO 2060](https://www.wago.com/infomaterial/pdf/51300133.pdf) is an SMT part with 4x rectangular solder pads, so there are no holes to speak of. The suggestion to mechanically remove the broken plastic pieces using cutters is helpful as this might help us access the solder joints better. I do hope we don't damage the traces by applying too much brute force here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a hot air gun or hot plate, and a hot-air rework station.
Such as a Bosch temperature adjustable hot air gun or a ceramic electric plate.

You will have to fabricate some jig to create a pre-heater.
The pre-heater warms the entire board to some temperature below melting of solder.
I guess 100C will work.

Then you can use your hot air to take the bad part off, apply some solder the pads with your iron and use the hot air or iron to apply the new part.